# Creating a Populator to duplicate the ProductPrimaryImagePopulator functionality

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have extended the default product type to also have a videos attribute that is identical to the identical to the images attribute, except for the name:

```
<itemtype code="Product" extends="GenericItem" autocreate="false" generate="false">
    <description>Extend the product type to also hold links to videos.</description>
    <attributes>
        <attribute qualifier="videos" type="MediaContainerList">
            <description>List of videos for a given product</description>
            <modifiers/>
            <persistence type="property"/>
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

I am now trying to copy the ProductPrimaryImagePopulator to set the videos in the Data object, but I am missing something obvious.  Here is the code and the error:

```
import de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.product.data.ImageData;
import de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.product.data.ImageDataType;
import de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.product.data.ProductData;
import de.hybris.platform.core.model.media.MediaContainerModel;
import de.hybris.platform.core.model.media.MediaModel;
import de.hybris.platform.core.model.product.ProductModel;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.dto.converter.ConversionException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ProductVideoPopulator<SOURCE extends ProductModel, TARGET extends ProductData>
        extends AbstractProductImagePopulator<SOURCE, TARGET> {
    @Override
    public void populate(final SOURCE productModel, final TARGET productData) throws ConversionException {
        final MediaContainerModel primaryImageMediaContainer = getPrimaryImageMediaContainer(productModel);
        if (primaryImageMediaContainer != null) {
            final List<ImageData> imageList = new ArrayList<ImageData>();

            // Use the first container as the primary image
            addImagesInFormats(primaryImageMediaContainer, ImageDataType.PRIMARY, 0, imageList);

            for (final ImageData imageData : imageList) {
                if (imageData.getAltText() == null) {
                    imageData.setAltText(productModel.getName());
                }
            }
            productData.setVideos(imageList);
        }
    }

    protected MediaContainerModel getPrimaryImageMediaContainer(final SOURCE productModel) {
        final MediaModel picture = (MediaModel) getProductAttribute(productModel, ProductModel.PICTURE);
        if (picture != null) {
            return picture.getMediaContainer();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The error

```
   [yjavac] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/riley/dev/work/hybrisdemo/core-customize/hybris/bin/custom/demo/demofacades/classes
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 1. ERROR in /Users/riley/dev/work/hybrisdemo/core-customize/hybris/bin/custom/demo/demofacades/src/com/nobiz/demo/facades/populators/ProductVideoPopulator.java (at line 15)
   [yjavac]     extends AbstractProductImagePopulator<SOURCE, TARGET> {
   [yjavac]             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] AbstractProductImagePopulator cannot be resolved to a type
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 2. ERROR in /Users/riley/dev/work/hybrisdemo/core-customize/hybris/bin/custom/demo/demofacades/src/com/nobiz/demo/facades/populators/ProductVideoPopulator.java (at line 17)
   [yjavac]     public void populate(final SOURCE productModel, final TARGET productData) throws ConversionException {
   [yjavac]                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] The method populate(SOURCE, TARGET) of type ProductVideoPopulator<SOURCE,TARGET> must override or implement a supertype method
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 2 problems (2 errors)
```

Another issue I know I will need to resolve is in the ProductModel.PICTURE, Eclipse is not showing me that value, what should I be using to get the videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AbstractProductImagePopulator cannot be resolved to a type

I'm guessing that you have not defined the dependencies.

AbstractProductImagePopulator exists in `commercefacades`. Make sure `demofacades` defines `commercefacades` as a dependency in `extensioninfo.xml`.

> Another issue I know I will need to resolve is in the
>   ProductModel.PICTURE, Eclipse is not showing me that value, what
>   should I be using to get the videos?

Since you added `Product.videos` in items.xml, something like `ProductModel.VIDEOS` should be available in `ProductModel`.

Make sure to resolve all build / compilation errors first. Then, check if it's all good. Additionally, you will also need to add the populator to the converter that will convert the ProductModel.